# __LINE__ equivalent in Javascript

Tags: javascript

Is there any way to get the source line number in Javascript, like `__LINE__` for C or PHP?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is a way, although more expensive: throw an exception, catch it immediately, and dig out the first entry from its stack trace.  See example [here](http://eriwen.com/javascript/js-stack-trace/) on how to parse the trace.  The same trick can also be used in plain Java (if the code is compiled with debugging information turned on).

**Edit**: Apparently not all browsers support this. The good news is (thanks for the comment, Christoph!) that some browsers export source file name and line number [directly through the `fileName` and `lineNumber` properties of the error object](http://books.google.hu/books?id=8oxJo5NITJUC&pg=PA204&lpg=PA204&dq=javascript+lineNumber+property&source=bl&ots=qkNTkbNKZR&sig=0Rs0BRj8wj-yTvdLUE9UJybd4TA&hl=en&sa=X&oi=book_result&resnum=1&ct=result).

Comment: browsers which add a stack trace to error objects might also expose a `lineNumber` property directly - no need for parsing there...

Answer (score 6):

The short answer is **no**.

The long answer is that depending on your browser you might be able to throw & catch an exception and pull out a stack trace.

I suspect you're using this for debugging (I hope so, anyway!) so your best bet would be to use [**Firebug**](http://getfirebug.com/).  This will give you a [`console`](http://getfirebug.com/console.html) object; you can call `console.trace()` at any point to see what your programme is doing without breaking execution.

Answer (score 3):

You can use this in vanilla JS:

```
function getLine(offset) {
    var stack = new Error().stack.split('\n'),
        line = stack[(offset || 1) + 1].split(':');
    return parseInt(line[line.length - 2], 10);
}

Object.defineProperty(window, '__LINE__', {
    get: function () {
        return getLine(2);
    }
});
```

You will now have access to the global variable `__LINE__`

Comment: For some weird reason this works fine in Chromium based browsers, but not as well using Firefox

Answer (score 2):

A `__LINE__` in C is expanded by a [preprocessor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preprocessor) which literally replaces it with the line number of the current input. So, when you see

```
printf("Line Number: %d\r\n", __LINE__);
```

the compiler sees:

```
printf("Line Number: %d\r\n", 324);
```

In effect the number (324 in this case) is HARDCODED into the program. It is only this *two-pass* mechanism that makes this possible.

I do not know how PHP achieves this (is it preprocessed also?).

Comment: Yes, PHP is preprocessed. In fact, it's a recursive acronym: PHP -> PHP: Hypertext Preprocessor. The acronym originally was for *Personal Home Pages* though.

Answer (score 2):

You can try to run C preprocessor (f.e. `cpp` from GNU Compiler Collection) on your javascript files -- either dynamically with each request or statically, by making this operation be applied every time you change your javascript files. I think the javascript syntax is similar enough for this to work.

Then you'd have all the power of C preprocessor.

Answer (score 1):

I think preprocessing makes more sense, in that it adds no runtime overhead. An alternative to the C preprocessor is using perl, as in the 2 step procedure below:

1 – add “Line # 999 \n”  to each line in the script that you want numbered, e.g.,

```
  alert ( "Line # 999 \n"+request.responseText);

2 – run the perl below:

cat my_js.js | perl -ane "{ s/Line # \d+ /Line # $. /; print $_;}" > C_my_js.js; mv  C_my_js.js  my_js.js
```

Answer (score 0):

There is one workaround.

Usually the  __ LINE __ combined with the  __ FILE __  is used for marking a locations in code and the marking is done to find that location later.

However, it is possible to achieve the same effect by using Globally Unique Identifiers (GUID-s) in stead of the __ LINE __ and __ FILE __. Details of the solution reside in the [COMMENTS.txt](https://github.com/martinvahi/mmmv_devel_tools/blob/master/src/mmmv_devel_tools/GUID_trace/COMMENTS.txt) of a BSD-licensed toolset that automates the process.

Comment: I don't understand... can you explain?